# How do I quit an action if they submitted something higher than what they had

Tags: python

I am making a pay system and I need help with quitting the action if their credits is too lower then what they're paying someone

This is a paying system, I have tried making a new line and doing it, I dont have any other soulutions. I'm new to python so yeah...

```
credits = 100
person = (input("Who do you want to pay?"))
numberpay = int(input("How much do you want to pay {person}?".format(person=person)))
accept = (input("Are you sure you want to pay {person} {numberpay} credits, Yes or no?".format(person=person, numberpay=numberpay)))
if accept.lower() == 'no':
    print("Your action to pay {person} {numberpay} credits was cancelled.".format(person=person, numberpay=numberpay))
if accept.lower() == 'yes':
    print("{numberpay} credits was taken from your account and given to {person}.".format(numberpay=numberpay, person=person))
    if numberpay ^ credits:
        print("Your action was cancelled due to a loss of credits.")
    totbal = ((credits) - (numberpay))
    print("Your current balance is now {totbal}.".format(totbal=totbal))
```

I expect it to say "Your action was cancelled due to a loss of credits." when they dont have enough credits, but it doesnt work. It just says it even if I have enough credits to give away.

Comment: I'm fairly sure `if numberpay ^ credits` is not the operation you had in mind

Answer (score 0):

Two immediate changes: use the correct operator and make sure that `totbal = ((credits) - (numberpay))` only executes when there are sufficient funds.

`^` is a bitwise exclusive or.  You should change

```py
if numberpay ^ credits:
```

to

```py
if numberpay - credits <= 0:
```

You need to include an else statement to handle the credit reduction and print message:

```py
    if numberpay - credits <= 0:
        print("Your action was cancelled due to a loss of credits.")
    else:
        # reduce the balance
        credits -= numberpay
        print("Your current balance is now {credits}.".format(credits=credits))
```

If you are using python3.6 or above, you could simplify your strings with fstrings.
For example:

```py
numberpay = int(input("How much do you want to pay {person}?".format(person=person)))
accept = (input("Are you sure you want to pay {person} {numberpay} credits, Yes or no?".format(person=person, numberpay=numberpay)))
```

would become

```py
numberpay = int(input(f"How much do you want to pay {person}?"))
accept = (input(v"Are you sure you want to pay {person} {numberpay} credits, Yes or no?"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to our community!

Here the right way on doing that (using you own code):

```
if accept.lower() == 'yes':
    print("{numberpay} credits was taken from your account and given to {person}.".format(numberpay=numberpay, person=person))
    if numberpay > credits:
        print("Your action was cancelled due to a loss of credits.")
    else:
        totbal = ((credits) - (numberpay))
    print("Your current balance is now {totbal}.".format(totbal=totbal))
```

please use `>` (greater then).

BTW in your code you subtracting `numberpay` from `credits` even if `numberpay` is greater then `credits`, which make no sense. Please see my way on doing that also...

Good luck!

Comment: Shoudln't `numberpay < credits`  should be `credits < numberpay`?

Comment: @DWD Sure, Thx!